# when trying establish a database connection in zend framework in models/users.php: Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_Users' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_Users' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\intern\lc.intern\application\controllers\AuthController.php on line 44

But Application_Models_Users class is already defined in \models\users.php

The following code is present in users.php

```
class Application_Models_Users extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name="users";
}
```

I even established a connection to database in application.ini like this ,

```
resources.db.adapter = 'PDO_MYSQL'
resources.db.params.host = 'localhost'
resources.db.params.dbname = 'lc.intern'
resources.db.params.username = 'root'
resources.db.params.password = ''
```

still I get the error ...
am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the class to be named: `Application_Model_Users` (note singular Model), not `Application_Models_Users`.

See the code for the default [module resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.11.11%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FApplication%2FModule%2FAutoloader.php) which shows that the class `Application_Model_XXX` is mapped to the file `application/models/XXX.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Check resource types, defined in Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader to know naming for other resources